# Replace Oracle Java with AdoptOpenJDK in Install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I had created installer with Install4j using Oracle Java. Now i have replaced Oracle java with AdoptOpenJDK. Everything is working fine except un-install welcome screen, buttons are not visible properly and also provided message is not visible.
Please can anyone suggest any possible fix for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: OpenJDK is fully support by the current version. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com with such an issue.

Comment: Shared jre option has resolved my issue. Thanks Ingo Kegel.